# How to rewrite and submit form at same time

Tags: javascript, forms, post, url-rewriting

There is a form that i want to submit and url rewrite at the same time. I can change url by adding `onsubmit="rewrite_form(event);"` option in form :

```
function rewrite_form(e) {    
  var form = document.forms[0];   // .getElementById("form1");
  window.location = '/search/' + form.f.value + '_' + form.t.value + '.htm/' + form.amt_from.value;            
  if (e && e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
  return false;
}
```

Url changes but other values of form not posted to url generated page.

Comment: you can use jQuery.clone to create a deep copy of a form

Answer (score 0):

Just change the form's action property instead.

```
function rewrite_form(e) {
    var form = documen.forms[0];

    form.action = 'newurl';
    //rest of code, make sure not to call e.preventDefault(); or return false
    //because the form will not get submitted
}
```

Comment: i change form.action but not working is there any error in my script:   function rewrite_form(e) {

                var form = document.getElementById("form1");
                window.location = '/travel/search/' + form.from.value + '_to_' + form.to.value + '.html/';
                var u = '/travel/search/' + form.from.value + '_to_' + form.to.value + '.html/';
                form.action =  window.location.u;
                if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                return false;
            }

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution:

```
    function rewrite_form() {
//Create custom link here
----------------------------
----------------------------------
//create form submit action
var url = '/search/' +'your custom link';
document.getElementById('FormId').action = url;
document.FormId.submit();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the solution I gave you... changing the form's action. Now if you had errors in the rest of your code you should have specified it.